Render block body until head script has finished running
Is there a way to prevent HTML body from rendering and executing scripts until a script loaded in the header has both loaded and executed. I know script tags can be render blocking while downloading, but I also want it to render block until finished execution.
E.g.
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- I have full control over what is in the head and this script -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='some-script.js' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- I have no control over what is in the body -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='some-other-script.js' />
  </body>
</html>

some-script.js - will load and do some JS execution which will x amount of time. I want to prevent some-other-script.js from downloading until the first script is complete.

Insert the second <script> element dynamically, at the end of the first script using document.body.insertAdjacentHTML.

Why is preventing the script from being fetched (not executed) important? And if the script is not marked "defered" or "async" then evaluation of the script will complete before the browser proceeds to the next script.

Unfortunately dynamically inserting the second script is not an option for me. I have full control over what is in the first script as well as the head of the document. Trying to problem solve within those constraints :3

"Render block body until head script has finished running" That's covered here, what you have will do that.  "I want to prevent some-other-script.js from downloading until the first script is complete." (my emphasis) It's hard to prove a negative, but I'm 99.9% sure you can't. Browsers optimize load time and one of the ways they do that is by downloading scripts in parallel with running other scripts (that is, by looking ahead).
